# Using equalsIgnoreCase in if statement and while loop

Tags: if-statement, do-while, equals-operator

```
    String wrd;

    do
    {
        wrd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word");
        if (!wrd.equalsIgnoreCase("last"))
        {
            if (wrd.contains("s") || wrd.contains("S"))
            {
                System.out.println(wrd + " does contain 's' or 'S'");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(wrd + " doesn't contain 's' or 'S'");
            }
        }
    }
    while (!wrd.equalsIgnoreCase("last"));
    System.out.println("Program Ended");
```

This program basically allows a user to enter any word in until he/she types the word "last".

If the word contains the letter 's' it should display the word + does contain 's' or 'S' else it should display word + doesn't contain 's' or 'S'.

Example: Words entered by user=

• John

• James

• Pie

• Sally

Result:

John does not contain 's' or 'S'

James does contain 's' or 'S'

Pie does not contain 's' or 'S'

Sally not contain 's' or 'S'

The program works but I need to change the if statement so that it recognises lower and uppercase 's' using the equalsIgnoreCase method instead of using

```
    wrd.contains("s") || wrd.contains("S")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this

```
String wrd;
    do {
         wrd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word s");
        if (wrd.toLowerCase().contains("s")) {
            System.out.println(wrd + " does contain 's' or 'S'");
        } else {
            System.out.println(wrd + " doesn't contain 's' or 'S'");
        }
    } while (!wrd.equalsIgnoreCase("last"));
    System.out.println("Program Ended");
```